# How should I implement this in Hibernate/ Spring?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, relational-database

I have a simple layout for a database. There are three tables:

Movie: move_id, title, ...

User: user_id, username, ...

Rating: rating, comment, ...

I would like to use the rating table as an intermediary, as in having it comprised of the following columns: rating, comment, user_id, movie_id.

I know this isn't the way you would want to do things, rather create another table for ratings and have it's own PK, but how would you implement this structure in Hibernate?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to add a surrogate ID to the rating table? As you said, this is the best solution.

Comment: To simply know if it was possible to model it in this other fashion. I am only testing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would structure my classes something like this:

```
public class Movie {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.movie")
  private List<Rating> ratings

}

public class Rating {

  @Embeddable
  public static class RatingId {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "movieId")
  private Movie movie;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "userId)
  private User user;

 // Equals and Hashcode which should check the associated tables @Ids

  }

  @EmbeddedId
  private RatingId id;

  private String comment;

  private int rating;

}

public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;


  private String userName;
}
```

The ratings table is a join table and has references to the User and Movie. The associations are inside a composite identifier since a Rating is uniquely identifier by a user and a movie (unless a user can post multiple ratings for a movie?). Using a composite key will ensure that if a user were to remove and then re-add a rating for a movie there would be no duplicate key violations - Hibernate does inserts  before deletes.

Comment: 1: If using the saveOrUpdate method, would it be affected differently? You mentioned that it handles inserts before deletes, but if the record is updated, there should be no concern right? <BR/> 2: The RatingId static class is a necessity and acts as a holder. I can understand that much. Using HQL, I would not ask for the RatingId explicitly but would query for the rating by the user and movie ids. Is this correct?

Comment: SaveOrUpdate will work fine. Updates should also work fine. You would load a Movie and gets it's ratings I would have thought. You could also put the List of ratings on a User and get all that users ratings. The above approach assumes that your User was saved before that user attempts to create any ratings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a composite primary key with user_id and movie_id for your Rating entity.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid